# How To save Json in Prisma 2.0?

Tags: prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I have `JSON` type in `MySQL` database.

This is valid JSON.

```
["Text 1","Text 2"]
```

And in `MySQL` I can execute:

```
UPDATE table_name SET col='["Text 1","Text 2"]' WHERE id=1;
```

But in `Prisma 2.0`

```
db.table_name.create({
        data: {
            col: ["Text 1", "Text 2"]
        }
    })
```

I have error like this:

```
Failed to validate the query `Error occurred during query validation & transformation:
Mutation (object)
  ↳ updateOneFile (field)
    ↳ data (argument)
      ↳ FileUpdateInput (object)
        ↳ text (field)
          ↳ Value types mismatch. Have: List([String("Text 1"), String("Text 2")]), want: Scalar(Json)` at `.Mutation.updateOneFile.data.FileUpdateInput.text`
    at PrismaClientFetcher.request (/home/daniel/pro/ocr/backend/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:1:85701)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5) {
  code: 'P2009',
  meta: {
    query_validation_error: 'Error occurred during query validation & transformation:\n' +
      'Mutation (object)\n' +
      '  ↳ updateOneFile (field)\n' +
      '    ↳ data (argument)\n' +
      '      ↳ FileUpdateInput (object)\n' +
      '        ↳ text (field)\n' +
      '          ↳ Value types mismatch. Have: List([String("Text 1"), String("Text 2")]), want: Scalar(Json)',
    query_position: '.Mutation.updateOneFile.data.FileUpdateInput.text'
  }
}
```

In this example:

```
My table name: "File"
My column name: "text"
```

> https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that this was fixed in

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@prisma/cli/v/2.0.0-alpha.1286

5 days ago

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2619

Quite similar problem was reported there

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2619

> Current status: `Waiting for documentation`

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2322

Progress:

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/milestone/35